# Case Statement using Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a data set of clients. Each have a Start date and an End Date. A client can have multiple lines with different Start dates and End dates. I have another data set with Claims info and i want to know if they had claims during the time frame there state and end date.

how can i write this?

```
 SELECT 
   M.[ID]
  ,EN.StartDate
  ,EN.EndDate
  ,[Has Cliams History] (Column to identify if yes or no)  

 FROM [Test].[dbo].[tblClients] M
 left join [test].[dbo].[tblCliams] EN on EN.ID = M.ID
```

Comment: Does tblClaims also have a date field to correlate the Date of the Claim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To illustrate the use of a case statement, the ClaimDate field represents the date of a  claim. The query would look something like this.

```
SELECT 
   M.[ID]
  ,EN.StartDate
  ,EN.EndDate
  ,CASE  
         WHEN ClaimDate between EN.StartDate AND EN.EndDate THEN 'yes' 
         ELSE 'no' 
       END [Has Cliams History]
 FROM [Test].[dbo].[tblClients] M
 left join [test].[dbo].[tblClaims] EN on EN.ID = M.ID
```

Comment: Hi @Amaury if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Your question needs to provide more clarity on the definition of both tables and the relationship between the two.  I am guessing you aren't actually joining a column called ID from both (at least I hope not).  Here is a stab at it based on the assumption you have a ClientID on the tblClaims and also that you support ongoing clients via a NULL EndDate.  Also assuming there are Start and End dates on tblClaims.

```
SELECT M.[ID]
    , CASE WHEN MAX(claim.ID) IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS HasClaimsHistory
FROM [Test].[dbo].[tblClients] client
LEFT JOIN [Test].[dbo].[tblCliams] claim on client.ID = claim.ClientID
    AND claim.StartDate >= client.StartDate
    AND (
        client.EndDate IS NULL /* ongoing support? */
        OR 
        claim.EndDate <= client.EndDate
    )
GROUP BY M.[ID]
    , CASE WHEN MAX(claim.ID) IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```